# Click on tab according to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a plugin for tabs, if I set a link to be 
www.mysite.com/page#tab2, how can that URL open the tab, here is their structure:

```
<div id="tabs" class="txtabs-wrap style1">
    <ul class="txtabs-nav top clearfix">
        <li class="first active">
            <a data-target="#tabs-0" data-toggle="tab">
            <span>Lorem</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <a data-target="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab">
            <span>Lorem</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Comment: Are you using `jQuery-ui` for `tabs`?

Comment: `a plugin` - please be more specific to allow us to help you. What plugin do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `HTML` structure:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    $('[data-target="' + window.location.hash + '"]')
        .closest('li').addClass('active')
        .siblings('li').removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: How should I set the links? Ex. to land on the second tab?

Comment: @tanya You can use the properties of the plugin you're using. Which plugin you're using?

Comment: Im using Xpert tabs http://www.themexpert.com/joomla-extensions/xpert-tabs, made the links like this:
index.php/link#tabs-e-1
because the HTML on the tabs is:
<li class="">
<a data-target="#tabs-e-1" data-toggle="tab">
link
</a>
</li>

Comment: Just added jQuery(window).on('load',  function(), all good, a million thanks!

Comment: Arrgh,... It has one more active class in the content:

<div class="txtabs-content">
<div id="tabs-e-0" class="txtabs-pane active in fade-slide">
<div id="tabs-e-1" class="txtabs-pane fade-slide">
<div id="tabs-e-2" class="txtabs-pane fade-slide">
<div id="tabs-e-3" class="txtabs-pane fade-slide">

Do I need to add more jQuery?